# Problems setting date object values in Javascript via new Date()

Tags: javascript, jquery, date

I have 3 buttons that modify a global date object in JS as per below.
Next and Prev work fine, but today seems to set the date to the 1st (with today being the 1st I assume) of whatever month *currentDate* currently holds. So if the user clicked back until they are in June, then click 'today' the date turns into 1st of June. What am I missing here?

```
    //  ===========================      Today button     ===========================
    $("#today").on("click", function(event) {
        var today = new Date();
        currentDate.setDate(today.getDate());
        loadApppointments(currentDate);
    });

    //  ===========================     Next Day button      ===========================
    $("#next_day").on("click", function(event) {
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 1);
        loadApppointments(currentDate);
    });


    //  ===========================      Previous Day button     ===========================
    $("#prev_day").on("click", function(event) {
        currentDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() - 1)
        loadApppointments(currentDate);
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because `setDate` sets only the day, not the full date.
And today is the first day of the month, so that's why 1st of June.
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date/setDate

Why can't you do this `currentDate = new Date();` ?

Comment: thanks... it's always was something simple like that ;)